# How to Create Different Directories with the Same Domain

Tags: redirect, dns

Hi Basically I have to make that

multiple domains have to point to the same machine

pero in different directories how can I do that?

i.e.

[www.sito1.com](http://www.sito1.com) must point to /root/pippobaudo

instead

[www.sito2.com](http://www.sito2.com) must point to /root/site2

which way can i do it?

Obviously in the same machine
p.s i am using windows and not linux
is there any script ?

I tried to insert an index.asp

following script :

```
"<%

dim host, pagina

host = LCase( request.servervariables("HTTP_HOST") )

SELECT CASE host

CASE "http://androideilbello.ddns.net/
pagina = "/tony/index.html"

CASE "http://iptest5/"
pagina = "/Dashboard/index.html"

CASE "www.topolino.com"
pagina = "default.htm"

CASE "www.minnie.it"
pagina = "/minnie/index.html"


END SELECT

Response.Redirect (pagina)

%>
"
```

but to no avail any other advice?

Comment: Generally you'll want to do this using [name based virtual hosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_hosting) configured on your (unspecified) HTTP server and not with ASP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I still can't figure out how I should do it could you please send me a script or a file where you explain everything?

Comment: You want me to point you to the right section of the manual for the **unspecified** HTTP server that you are using but still haven't named?

Comment: Yes please sir.

Comment: @TonyGiuga he meant that in a sarcastic way. Since you haven't specified which HTTP server you are using, there's no way he can provide a specific solution to your problem. Please change the question (and tags) to what server configuration you need to do for enabling this redirection.

Answer (score 0):

The commenters have suggested that you will need a HTTP/web server for that. Here a suggestion: NGINX

Here two links to get you started:

- Installation:
  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-open-source/
- Usage as a web server:
  https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/web-server/

You can specify server names to point to directories on your system: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

So a very rudimentary example (meaning it is not a full configuration example and might not work for you in that state) would be:

```
server {
listen       80  default_server;

server_name  www.sito1.com;

    location / {
        root /root/pippobaudo;
    }
}
```

Here is a full example configuration: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/full/